# How to use CASE statement inside a WHERE with an IN clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am trying to do the following (pseudocode since it doesn't compile):

```
declare showListedOrSold  int = 1 -- get value from config table

select *
from table
where CASE WHEN @showListedOrSold = 0 THEN id IN (1, 2, 5, 6, 10, 11) 
             WHEN @showListedOrSold = 1 THEN id IN (1, 5, 6, 10, 11) 
             WHEN @showListedOrSold = 2 THEN id IN (2) 
      END
```

Basically depending on value of `showListedOrSold`, it should bring back certain `id` values.

The statement is not liking the IN clause.  What is the correct syntax for this use case?

Comment: Stay away from the CASE solutions as they're not SARGable and will create performance problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could solve this by using OR instead of CASE:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE (@showListedOrSold = 0 AND id IN (1, 2, 5, 6, 10, 11))
        OR (@showListedOrSold = 1 AND id IN (1, 5, 6, 10, 11))
        OR (@showListedOrSold = 2 AND id IN (2))
```

Comment: I know.  That's the way I have it, but it's so not elegant.

Comment: It would be more elegant to store the id to showlistedorsold relationship in a table, then you could just join: FROM table INNER JOIN newtable on table=id = newtable.id and @showListedOrSold = newtable.showListedOrSold

Comment: It would, but feels like an overkill since I only need to perform this query once in my sproc.

Comment: Then use a table variable or temp table as Luis Cazares suggests below.

Answer (score 7):

If you want an "elegant solution", you might want to consider store these values in a table that can be used in your query.

```
CREATE TABLE #ValidIds(
    ShowListedOrSold int,
    id int);

INSERT INTO #ValidIds
VALUES( 0, 1),
      ( 0, 2),
      ( 0, 5),
      ( 0, 6),
      ( 0, 10),
      ( 0, 11),
      ( 1, 1),
      ( 1, 5),
      ( 1, 6),
      ( 1, 10),
      ( 1, 11),
      ( 2, 2);

SELECT *
FROM table t
JOIN #ValidIds v ON t.id = v.id
AND v.ShowListedOrSold = @ShowListedOrSold;
```

Comment: And if you already have a config table that stores `ShowListedOrSold`, you could create this mapping table, and set the `ShowListedOrSold` value (in the config table) as a FK to the mapping table.

Comment: That's a bit of an overkill for my situation.  This query is executed only once and this combination of numbers isn't reused anywhere.  But elegant solution nonetheless.

Comment: The advantage is that if you have a permanent table for this, you could simply add values there instead of changing the code if more ids become available.

Answer (score 5):

This starts to get rather complicated.  I might recommend a `join` approach:

```
select t.*
from table t join
     (values (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 5), (0, 6), (0, 10), (0, 11),
             (1, 1), (1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 10), (1, 11),
             (2, 2)
     ) v(slos, id)
     on t.slos = @showListedOrSold and
        v.id = s.id
```

You can easily expand this to show all rows if the variable is `null`:

```
     on (t.slos = @showListedOrSold and
         v.id = s.id
        ) or
        @showListedOrSold is null
```

Answer (score 2):

the way case works, you'd have to return a value, then check the value.

```
declare @showListedOrSold int = 1 -- get value from config table

select  *
from    [table]
where   (case
            when @showListedOrSold = 0 and  id in (1, 2, 5, 6, 10, 11) then 1
            when @showListedOrSold = 1 and  id in (1, 5, 6, 10, 11) then 1
            when @showListedOrSold = 2 and  id in (2) then 1
        else 0
        end) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could construct the SQL statement and then Execute it:

```
declare  @showListedOrSold Int = 1
Declare @vSQL VarChar(200)

Set @vSQL = 'select * from #tbl where id In '
Set @vSQL = @vSQL + 
                    CASE WHEN @showListedOrSold = 0 THEN '(1, 2, 5, 6, 10, 11)'
                         WHEN @showListedOrSold = 1 THEN '(1, 5, 6, 10, 11)' 
                         WHEN @showListedOrSold = 2 THEN '(2)'
                    END

Execute(@vSQL)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can give it like a sub query in WHERE clause:

```
select *
from table
where @showListedOrSold in (select  (CASE WHEN @showListedOrSold = 0 THEN id IN (1, 2, 5, 6, 10, 11) 
             WHEN @showListedOrSold = 1 THEN id IN (1, 5, 6, 10, 11) 
             WHEN @showListedOrSold = 2 THEN id IN (2) 
      END) as ABCD from table)
```

Comment: I like the slightly recursive nature of it.

Comment: It won't even compile

Comment: Case is an expression, it is used to return a scalar value. You are attempting to use to control logical flow which it cannot do.